# UICollectionView can't select after scroll

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3

My UICollectionView stop handling tap after scroll

DidSelect isn't called anymore after the scroll

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("didSelectItemAt")
        }
    }
```

A gesture inside the cell also isn't called after scroll:

```
override open func awakeFromNib() {
        // Initialization code
        let tapUpInside = UITapGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(MainCollectionViewCell.tapPressButtonUP(_:)))
        let longPress: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(MainCollectionViewCell.longPressButton(_:)))
        longPress.delegate = self;
        longPress.cancelsTouchesInView = false;
        self.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have added a Custom gesture below delegate is not called

> override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

For second part of your Question Add the gesture to content View of UICollectionView cell and check

```
self.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

I Suggest you to add a Long Press gesture on your UICollectionView and then Determine which CollectionViewCell overlaps with long pressed point so that you can get the selected CollectionViewCell